# Is there a way to use grep regex search multiline and lazy?

Tags: regex, ubuntu, grep

Is there a way to use grep multiline and lazy?
I have a text file with an XML in it.

The search pattern is similar to

```
<i>something.*?}</i>
```

- Pzo option doesn't work multiline
- Ezo option doesn't work lazy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: no patterns - regex is always bad idea when parsing xml/html

Comment: yup, don't use regex for this case... also, for multiline Pzo, use `(?s)` at start of regex..

Comment: Thank you, I know that sed or python would do it. However I'm curious about grep + regex

Comment: `curious about grep + regex` .... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags